# Error Importing Cost from Excel to Ms Project

Tags: ms-project

I am trying to import data from Excel to Ms Project. I have recorded a Map file in Ms Project and everything works fine, I can import Tasks, Resources and Assignments, but I have a problem importing the Cost field in Assignments.

I have both Cost and Material Type Resources. Cost resource assignment imports without problem, for them there is no calculation like resource_rate*units for cost, you just enter the cost manually. However, for the Material resource assignments, I leave the Cost field blank, as Ms Project calculates it itself for those resources.

My Excel Assignment Sheet simply looks like this:

| Units | Cost | Task_ID | Resource_ID |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | $100 | 1 | 1 | => This resource type is Cost and imports without problem |
| 2.54 |  | 1 | 2 | => This resource type is Material and gives error |

When I start Import I get the below error, And When I click "No" everything is imported correctly, but I have to bypass the error, is there a way I can bypass this error? (Column 4 is "Cost" field in my Assignment Sheet)

[image]

Comment: As this is not a programming question, but rather an issue with the MS Project application, the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) site is the appropriate place for this question. The question is well-defined and well-presented--just create an account on the PM site & copy this over as-is.

Comment: Try splitting the Assignments import into two parts with two different maps--one for Cost resources and one for the Material resources and leave off the Cost field for the latter.

Comment: Hi @RachelHettinger, thank you for your comment again. Actually I am trying to do this import by code, opening the Excel file from an ASP.Net application with `projectApplication.FileOpenEx`  which gives the same result as trying to import the excel file from Ms Project manually. I am going to try to import different types of resources with different map files as you have suggested and inform you about the result accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, on the map file I have deleted the Cost column from the assignments for Material resources and could import without errors.